# React with GraphQL: TypeError: parse is not a function

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am currently trying to replace my restful call to retrieve all my `articles` from the server with a call to a graphql endpoint. I have tested the following query with `GraphiQL` and it returns the expected data. I've also posted to the endpoint manually with fiddler and it functions as expected. My issue is trying to call the endpoint from a react component using `Apollo`.

I am currently receiving the following error:

```
TypeError: parse is not a function
```

an example of the data which is returned from my graphql query:

```
{
  "data": {
    "articles": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "description": "desc1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "description": "desc2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and the component in full:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Glyphicon } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import { Query } from "react-apollo";
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export class ArticlesIndex extends Component {
  displayName = ArticlesIndex.name

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { articles: [], loading: true };
  }

  componentDidMount () {
      <Query
        query={gql`
        query GetArticleData {
          articles {
            id
            description
          }
        }
        `}
      >
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
      if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

        console.log(data.articles);
        this.setState({articles: data.articles, loading: false});
    }}
      </Query>
  }

  renderArticlesTable = articles => {
    return (
      <table className='table'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {articles.map(article =>
            <tr key={article.id}>
              <td>{article.id}</td>
              <td>{article.title}</td>
              <td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: article.description }}></td>
              <td>
                <LinkContainer to={'/articles/edit/' + article.id}>
                    <Glyphicon glyph='edit' />
                </LinkContainer>
            </td>
            <td onClick={(e) => this.deleteArticle(e, article.id) }>
              <Glyphicon glyph='trash' />
            </td>
            </tr>
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }

  render() {
    let contents = this.state.loading
      ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
      : this.renderArticlesTable(this.state.articles);

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Articles</h1>
        <LinkContainer to={'/articles/create'}>
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-default">New Article</button> 
        </LinkContainer>
        {contents}
      </div>
    );
  }

  deleteArticle(event, id) { 
    fetch('https://localhost:44360/api/articles/' + id, {  
        method: 'DELETE'
    }).then((response) => response.json())  
        .then((responseJson) => {  
            var deletedId = responseJson.id;

        this.setState({
          articles: this.state.articles.filter(function( obj ) {
            return obj.id !== deletedId;
          })
        });

    })  
  }
}
```

Note that my breakpoints are not being hit on the server side and no request is being made to the server.

In `App.js`, I've set up `ApolloClient` and `ApolloProvider` as follows:

```
client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "https://localhost:44360/graphql"
  });

  render() {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={this.client}>
        <Layout>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home} exact={true} />
          <Route path='/articles' component={ArticlesIndex} exact={true} />
          <Route path='/articles/create' component={ArticlesCreate} exact={true} />
          <Route path='/articles/edit/:id' component={ArticlesEdit} exact={true} />
        </Layout>
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
```

Why is this happening and how can I overcome it?

EDIT: as I've seen suggested elsewhere, I downgraded the `graphql` npm package to version `0.12.3` and it resulted in no errors in console or otherwise but the screen stays at `Loading...` still with no request ever being sent to the server.

EDIT 2: I've now tried every workaround listed [here](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag/issues/155#issuecomment-390032903) and after trying the suggestion to alter the webpack config, the page will not error out as before however no request is still being sent to the server and `Loading...` forever stays on the page. Breakpoints in my `componentDidMount` function are being hit but nothing seems to be happening.

EDIT 3: If I replace the graphql call to get data with the following restful call, everything behaves as normal but the purpose of this project is to explore react with graphql. The restful call that functions properly and that I'm trying to replace is below:

```
fetch('https://localhost:44360/api/Articles/')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ articles: data, loading: false });
      });
```

Comment: Do you have a schema to check the query you wrote, I doubt that's the correct way to write it but if u do have schema double check.

Comment: It is a problem with Graphql version, can you please share what version you are using? u may need to downgrade or upgrade it.

Comment: @RachidRhafour I was originally on graphql version 14.1.1 and tried downgrading to 0.12.3 to resolve the issue which resulted in the behavior stated in the "EDIT" section of my post

Comment: I'm not sure which version may work but I'm using Graphql v`14.0.2` with "graphql-tag": "2.10.0" npm version is `5.6.0`

Comment: changed to teh packages you mentioned and still getting the same error `TypeError: parse is not a function` is my usage the same as yours? I'm still getting no request ever sent to teh server and that error happens upon navigating to the page

Comment: can you have that example in code sandbox and share it with me so I can take a look?

Comment: the simple project this is included in is located at https://bitbucket.org/greghofman/reacttofacts/src/development/ this includes a .net core backend that includes graphql. The React app is located at ReactToFacts.Client

Comment: I guess I found why, give me a second plz

Comment: check my answer please, let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: can you check my answer?

Comment: that works- can you please add some explanation to the code you've changed? particularly using `export default withApollo(ArticlesIndex);`

Comment: I did some explanation to my answer, please check and let me know if they are clear  for you @GregH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used JSX in `componentDidMount`, instead you can do `this.props.client.query({query: GET_ARTICLES})`, I tested it, it's working.

Change your `articles/index.js` to

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Glyphicon } from "react-bootstrap";
import { LinkContainer } from "react-router-bootstrap";
import { Query, withApollo } from "react-apollo";
import gql from "graphql-tag";

const GET_ARTICLES = gql`
query GetArticleData {
    articles {
    id
    description
    }
}
`;
class ArticlesIndex extends Component {
state = { articles: [], loading: true };
displayName = ArticlesIndex.name;

componentDidMount = () => {
    const { client } = this.props;
    client
    .query({ query: GET_ARTICLES })
    .then(({ data: { articles } }) => {
        if (articles) {
        this.setState({ loading: false, articles });
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("err", err);
    });
};

renderArticlesTable = articles => {
    return (
    <table className="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {articles.map(article => (
            <tr key={article.id}>
            <td>{article.id}</td>
            <td>{article.title}</td>
            <td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: article.description }} />
            <td>
                <LinkContainer to={"/articles/edit/" + article.id}>
                <Glyphicon glyph="edit" />
                </LinkContainer>
            </td>
            <td onClick={e => this.deleteArticle(e, article.id)}>
                <Glyphicon glyph="trash" />
            </td>
            </tr>
        ))}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    );
};

render() {
    let contents = this.state.loading ? (
    <p>
        <em>Loading...</em>
    </p>
    ) : (
    this.renderArticlesTable(this.state.articles)
    );

    return (
    <div>
        <h1>Articles</h1>
        <LinkContainer to={"/articles/create"}>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-default">
            New Article
        </button>
        </LinkContainer>
        {contents}
    </div>
    );
}

deleteArticle(event, id) {
    fetch("https://localhost:44360/api/articles/" + id, {
    method: "DELETE"
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => {
        var deletedId = responseJson.id;

        this.setState({
        articles: this.state.articles.filter(function(obj) {
            return obj.id !== deletedId;
        })
        });
    });
}
}

export default withApollo(ArticlesIndex);
```

change your `App.js` to

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router";
import { Layout } from "./components/Layout";
import { Home } from "./components/Home";
import ArticlesIndex from "./components/articles/Index";
import { ArticlesCreate } from "./components/articles/Create";
import { ArticlesEdit } from "./components/articles/Edit";
import { ApolloProvider } from "react-apollo";
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";

export default class App extends Component {
  displayName = App.name;

  client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "https://localhost:44360/graphql"
  });

  render() {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={this.client}>
        <Layout>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} exact={true} />
          <Route path="/articles" component={ArticlesIndex} exact={true} />
          <Route
             path="/articles/create"
             component={ArticlesCreate}
             exact={true}
          />
          <Route
            path="/articles/edit/:id"
            component={ArticlesEdit}
            exact={true}
          />
        </Layout>
      </ApolloProvider>
     );
   }
}
```

The issue was that you were using JSX inside of `ComponentDidMount`, that is not supported in react, in order to use query in life cycle methods, you should wrap the component with `withApollo` and that will add client to the props (thus `export default withApollo(ArticlesIndex);`), then you can do `this.props.client.query` in `componentDidMount` and then you can setState.